# Error 404 when trying to set up a Bottle-powered web app on Apache/mod_wsgi

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, bottle

I am a beginner programmer. I started using Python and Bottle for a small web app to print a form, so far so good. The real issue is configuring Apache and `mod_wsgi`, as my knowledge is almost none.

**My problem**: I keep getting this error:

> Error 404: Not Found
>
> Sorry, the requested URL /factura/ caused an error: Not found

In work they gave me and address redirecting to a IP:port; after some days of reading Apache docs and looking examples through the web I managed to set up the configuration so my VirtualHost doesn't breaks the others virtualhosts already running. The config looks like this (based on the bottle tutorial deployment section):

```
Listen port
NameVirtualHost IP:port

<VirtualHost IP:port>
    ServerName IP:port

    WSGIDaemonProcess factura processes=1 threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/factura/app.wsgi

    <Directory /var/www/factura>
        WSGIProcessGroup factura
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My `app.wsgi` is almost the same as the one in the Bottle tutorial-deployment section. I only added the line `sys.stdout = sys.stderr`:

```
import sys, os, bottle

# Change working directory so relative paths (and template lookup) work again
sys.path = ['/var/www/factura'] + sys.path
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# Error output redirect
# Exception KeyError in 'threading' module
sys.stdout =  sys.stderr

import factura
application = bottle.default_app()
```

Here is a bit of the python code which is related to Bottle:

```
from lib import bottle

app = bottle.Bottle()

#serves files in folder 'static'
@app.route('/static/:path#.+#', name='static')
def ...

@app.route("/factura")
@bottle.view("factura")
def ...

@app.route("/print_factura", method="POST")
def ...
```

I have read some of the others question similar to this, but I can't manage to see what I'mm missing. I suppose the problem is in `app.wsgi`?

**UPDATE**

file structure

```
/var/www/factura/       ## .py files
                /views  ## here is the web template
                /static ## .css and .js of template
                /lib    ## package with bottle and peewee source files
                /data   ## inkscape file to play with
                /bin    ## backup stuff in repo, not used in code
```

Apache error log only shows

`Exception KeyError: KeyError(-1211426160,) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.pyc'> ignored`
that is a warning from wsgi/python issues, harmless by [wsgi issue 197](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/issues/detail?id=197)

**UPDATE 2** working

 added `@app.route("/factura/")` notice the trail slash, that with the change in app import `from factura import app as application` those two together made it work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create your application explicitly:

```
app = bottle.Bottle()
```

then you should import it in your `app.wsgi` instead of `application = bottle.default_app()`:

```
from factura import app as application
```

But what is far important is this. In your WSGI file, you do `import bottle`, yet in the app code file, you do `from lib import bottle`. As you have explained, you have two copies of Bottle: one installed server-wide, another under the `lib` directory.

That's why you were receiving `404 Not Found`. You were actually working with one instance of the library (creating `app`), and then giving Apache a different (`default_app`) *from a different instance of the library!*

It started to work okay when you began to return the proper `app`.

Comment: just noticed that BUT I ask for /factura the trialing slash is added in the apache error. in static folder there is a .css and I get the same error (the trail slash seems to have the same behaviour)

Comment: Didnt see that issue testing in bottle in localhost. When I get back to work will try what the docs you linked says, thank you ofr the fast answer

Comment: @mraistlin: I've updated my answer with some more things for you to check. :)

Comment: updated with what you asked and after that working :D (now I only get an acces denied issue within my program but that should be easy fixable with directories acces, and not related to this question). should I be worried about the trail slash being added?. Regarding the `import bottle` you asked my first day with hands on this workmate said to install bottle with aptitue on the server, thats why can call it there

Comment: @mraistlin: I've updated my answer with a more detailed explanation of the behavior. If your problem is resolved, consider accepting the answer.